# Theme Plugins Not working in Andriod studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I Install a new version of Android studio and install the theme Plugins in it but it can't working.it just showing only default themes. can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you restarted the Studio after installing the plugin?

Comment: @Tonnie yes! I have restarted but its not working

Comment: Which Plugin is that so that I try on my end and see

Comment: Material UI Theme

Comment: @Tonnie I have a new version of Android Studio (Arctic Fox)

Comment: I Installed Material Theme on Arctic Fox and it is working on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Please click the Material Theme Icon on the Studio Toolbar as shown below.

[image]

This will start the Wizard and you can configure the appearance of Android Studio.

Let me know if you can see this icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194925628?pli=1) and will be fixed in the next minor release.

In the meantime do this
"

1. Rename the /lib/gson-2.7.jar file to gson-2.7.jar.disabled.
2. Restart Studio.

where studio-installation-directory is by default C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio on Windows and /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents on Mac.

Should you experience a problem updating to the next Studio version later on, you may rename the file back and retry the update installation.
"

Answer (score 0):

1. We will now add monokai theme of sublime to Android Studio. First of all download the jar file from my [Github](https://github.com/hritikrommie/Android-studio-themes). To import this theme to our Android Studio, go to the File > Manage IDE Settings > Import Settings…

[image]

2. After clicking on Import Settings, a new dialog box will be open like this.
   [image]
3. Now you have to select the downloaded jar file or you can do drag and drop too then click on Ok.

[image]

4. After clicking Ok, a new dialog box will open where we can select what component we want to import from jar file to editor.

[image]

5. Here select both colors and schemes and then click Ok. After this, a new box will be open.

[image]

6. Click on the Restart button to reload the settings. Here you can see the new theme. You can follow the same steps while importing any jar files.

[image]